# Why did Nintendo leave digital assets in Ocarina of Time that were unused?

Tags: game-design, nintendo, development-speed

I am aware that this is not unique to this game. I also wonder about this in general, but this game was what prompted me to ask about it, especially as there's so much of it.

Yes, I know that there is no extra cost to just "burn" the extra, unused data onto the ROM chips as long as the total size fits in the decided-upon ROM size, but should it not be a "work pride" thing to at least spend some time toward the very end to just remove all the stuff that isn't actually in the final game? Why keep it there and thus distribute all that "development stuff" to every end user?

Did they intend for people to eventually find it, like some sort of "Easter egg"? Was it a way to attempt to "trick" users who would early on hack the game data and confuse them with assets and code that does nothing, to encourage rumors about hidden places and whatnot?

I'm trying to understand the mentality of developing the most anticipated, 5+ years in the making mega game (and known to obviously be this long before its release), only to then not do the final "clean-up" just before releasing the game. To me, it feels like preparing for many years for the biggest party ever, only to not take out the heaps of trash left over in various rooms of the mansion where the party is to be held. Sure, most won't see it, but it's there, and it would surely annoy me beyond words.

Why did they keep around all that unnecessary, unused data?

Comment: This site isn't really for questions of historical curiosity. It's for helping *you* make *your own* games and game mods *today*. Are you having trouble pruning unused assets in a game that you are making?

Comment: @DMGregory I first ask on Arquade. They "close" my question and tell me to ask here. I ask here, and I get the same f****g BS. This site is unbelievable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question can only be answered by people who were directly involved in the development of that particular game, and even if those people find this question, they are probably under an NDA so they are not allowed to answer.

Comment: You should always check the [help] section on a site to see what's on-topic for that site. Folks on Arqade mostly are not users here — they're not experts on what's on-topic for this site. You've also been told before, when you asked your last question, that what we do here is help with games being developed by you, not speculate about decisions made by other developers in existing games.

Comment: To give you some closure: in general, this type of stray data often piles up due to inadequate tooling identifying what assets are unused. If you don't have a way to absolutely guarantee that an asset is never referenced anywhere, then there's always a risk that deleting it introduces a new bug or crash right before shipping, which QC testing might not find and flag in time. (Maybe a few pixels from an unused item texture got used in the corner of one optional sidequest area, and that area now crashes if the texture is deleted). So leaving assets that still fit on-ROM and aren't seen is safer.